# Android peer to peer app using Sockets

Tags: android, sockets, client-server, p2p

I wish to build a simple peer-peer app using Sockets. A accepts a number and sends it to B. Then B returns the square of the number back to A.

A sends to B on port 6000 and B sends back to A on port 8000. So both the machines act as clients when they must send, and as servers when they must receive.

But isn't it true that a server should be started BEFORE a client ? So, whats the logical solution to making this app ?

---

Here is the Server's code

```
package com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketserver;
```

.....

```
public class Server extends Activity {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket clientSock;

    Handler updateConversationHandler;

    Thread serverThread = null;
    Thread clientThread = null;

    private TextView text;

    public static final int SERVERPORT = 5000;
    public static final int CLIENTPORT = 8000;

    private static final String CLIENT_IP = "10.0.2.2";

    protected IRemote mService;
    private boolean bound = false;
    Intent it;

    private boolean test = false;

    private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

                @Override
                public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mService = null;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("IRemote", "Binding - Service disconnected");
                }

                @Override
                public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mService = IRemote.Stub.asInterface((IBinder) service);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("IRemote", "Binding is done - Service connected");
                }
           };

    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        unbindService(mServiceConnection);
    };


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);

        updateConversationHandler = new Handler();

        this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
        this.serverThread.start();

        it = new Intent();
        it.setAction("com.example.mynewclient.RemoteService");

        //it= new Intent(this,IRemote.class);

        //TEMP
        bound = getApplicationContext().bindService(it, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        Log.d("SERVER", bound ? "Binding is done - Service connected" : "Binding Failed");

        this.clientThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
        this.clientThread.start();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
//          EditText et = findViewById(R.id.text);
            String str = text.getText().toString();//et.getText().toString();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(clientSock.getOutputStream())),
                    true);
            out.println(345+"\n");

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();               

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception 3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    class ServerThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                try {

                    socket = serverSocket.accept();

                    CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                    new Thread(commThread).start();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

        private Socket clientSocket;

        private BufferedReader input;

        public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {

            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

            try {

                this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void run() {

            BufferedWriter writer;

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                try {

                    String read = input.readLine();

                    updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));

                    //writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(this.clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
                    //writer.write("Server Echos to client");
                    //writer.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
        private String msg;

        public updateUIThread(String str) {
            this.msg = str;
        }

        @Override
        public void run(){

            String message;
            BufferedReader input;

            if(mService == null)
            {
                Log.d("TAG 0", "Inside mservice==null");

                Intent it = new Intent();
                it.setAction("com.example.mynewclient.RemoteService");
                //it.setClassName( "com.example.myclient","com.example.myclient.IRemoteService" );
                //binding to remote service
//              bindService(it, mServiceConnection, Service.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            }


            int f = Integer.parseInt(msg);

            try{
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Result -> Add ->"+mIRemoteService.getSum(3,4), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                message = Integer.toString(mService.getSum(f,f));
                text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"The sum is: "+ message + "\n");

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                System.out.println(e.toString());
                Log.e("EXCEPTION 3", e.toString());
                f = f+f;
                message = "Not Successful";

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }

        }

        //TEMP Commented
        /*@Override
        public void run() {
            text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"Client Says: "+ msg + "\n");
        }*/
    }

    class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            BufferedReader input;

            try {

                Log.d("SERVER", "Client - thread 1");

                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(CLIENT_IP);

                clientSock = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

                //input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSock.getInputStream()));

                ///////////////////// 

                Log.d("SERVER", "Client - thread 2");

                //TEMP Commented
                //input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSock.getInputStream()));

                input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSock.getInputStream()));

                Log.d("SERVER", "Client - thread 3");

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "exception 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "exception 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Here's the client:

```
package com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient;
....
public class Client extends Activity {

    private Socket thisSocket;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    private TextView text;

    private static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "10.0.2.2";

    private static final int CLIENTPORT = 8000;

    Handler updateConversationHandler;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();

        new Thread(new ServerThread()).start();

    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
            String str = et.getText().toString();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(thisSocket.getOutputStream())),
                    true);
            out.println(str);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("SERVER ERROR",e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("SERVER ERROR",e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("SERVER ERROR",e.toString());
        }
    }

    class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            BufferedReader input;

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

                thisSocket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

                input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(thisSocket.getInputStream()));

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

//TEMP  COMMENTED

    class ServerThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(CLIENTPORT);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                try {

                    socket = serverSocket.accept();

                    Log.d("CLIENT TAG", "Listening to server");

                    CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                    new Thread(commThread).start();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("TAG Client 1", "IOException");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.d("TAG Client 2", e.toString());
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Client interrupted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

        private Socket clientSocket;

        private BufferedReader input;

        public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {

            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

            try {

                this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));

                Log.d("TAG Client 4", "Input from server"+input.toString());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("TAG Client 5", "Input from server");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("TAG Client 6", "Input from server");
            }
        }

        public void run() {

            BufferedWriter writer;

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                try {

                    String read = input.readLine();

                    updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));

                    //writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(this.clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
                    //writer.write("Server Echos to client");
                    //writer.close();

                    Log.d("TAG Client 7", "Input from server");

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("TAG Client 8", e.toString());
                }
            }
        }

    }

    class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
        private String msg;

        public updateUIThread(String str) {
            this.msg = str;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"Client Says: "+ msg + "\n");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Abhishek> Did you get this to work?

Comment: Jasper, I eventually did. It was nearly 2 and a half years ago, and I've moved on from the organization and that project, which is why I don't remember how it got working finally.

Comment: Thankyou Abhishek.

Answer (score 2):

The distinction between client and server is not made by who is sending or receiving data. In many cases, both server and client do both. The point of peer-to-peer is that there is no server/client relationship.

That being said, both your applications should run and start listening before you send anything, unless it's always A that sends first, in which case you have a client/server relationship.

Hope that helps.

Edit: Should probably mention this: You usually use multiple threads for networking, to keep listening on at least one port while the rest of the program executes.

Comment: LeShadow, thanks for the reply. Yes, B does send the number first, while A sends the result back (its square). So it does look more like a client-server. In both A and B, I have created a client thread to send data to the other. To receive data, A and B have threads leading to a UIThread. I start A first, and its able to receive the number from B, calculate the square and send it back. But B doesn't receive it (or doesn't show it has).

Comment: The way you do it is fine, in theory. Could you post some more details about your testing environment or code snippets?

Comment: OK I'll post the code in about 18 hours time as I'm out of office now.

Comment: I've added the code now. Note : getSum returns the square of the number.
So, basically I've created 2 SETS of ports: 6000 & 5000 for client to server. 8000 & 8000 is from Server back to client.

I've also modified the client to act as the server with a listener thread and UI thread etc. But it doesn't get any input from server. That's the problem.

Comment: Update: In the Client side, in the method ServerThread (that listens to the server), after the line 
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(CLIENTPORT);

I get java.net.bindException EADDRINUSE (Address already in use).

Comment: I added the following code snippet at ServerThread method of the client:
if (serverSocket==null){
serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true); 
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(); 
serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(CLIENTPORT));
}

Now that error seems to have gone but there's still no connection.

Comment: But yet, the question remains which should be started first ? If I start B, its able to accept numbers from A, but A cannot get data back from B. On the otehr hand, if I start B first, I can't send to A in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a long-connection Server for each client(like A,B,C,D.....)，A send msg to Server and forward to D.